# How do I bevel the "corner" edges of a solidified mesh using only modifiers?

Tags: bevel, solidify-modifier

I'm making a model that has a solidify modifier, and after that is a bevel modifier with the Weight limit method. I've marked every outer edge of the model with 100% bevel weight, but the edges on the solidified mesh that originated from the corners of the original mesh don't get marked. I'm wondering if there's a way to do so without having to apply the solidify modifier and mark the new edges manually. I know that using the Angle limit method fixes this issue, but it's harder to control and can add unwanted bevels on sharper corners.

Here's some examples to show what I mean using a subdivided plane:

Base mesh:

[image]

Solidified mesh:

[image]

Solidified mesh with weight-based bevels at the outer edges:

[image]

Solidified mesh with angle-based bevels (This is the result I'm looking for, just without having to actually use the Angle limit method):

[image]

To clarify, the resulting bevel corners must have geometry that joins at the center rather than the top, so that the mesh can be bent to a further extent without scaling down the bevels or overlapping them:

[image]

If anyone could help it would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

First in your modifier stack add a bevel modifier set to vertices, select the corner vertices and set their bevel weight.

[image]

**EDIT**
Adding a remesh modifier at the end will give you something like what you're looking for. Not exactly, but it's probably as good as you're going to get without delving into Geometry Nodes.
You'll have to play with the voxel size to get it just right.
[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you for responding. Unfortunately this method doesn't work for me since the second bevel clips into itself at sharper angles. Enabling clamp overlap on the second bevel modifier technically solves this but it also shrinks those bevels to be able to fit. The bevel corners must be made of quads that joint at the center, rather than the top. Basically, a corner of a quadsphere instead than a UV sphere.

Comment: HI @CalderCockatoo. You should try being more specific with your question. I can only provided an answer to the question you asked ;)  Bevels will always overlap and break your geometry if they become to large, the only way around this is to remove any edge loops that are too close to the edge you wish to bevel. In the examples you gave in your question, most of the geo in the base mesh is redundant.

Comment: I have edited my post to be more clear.

Comment: I've updated my answer with something close....